# Format Data: Make Columns to Rows (and other way around)

Tags: emacs, elisp

Consider this case: I have some data which looks like this:

> 1.9170000e+03 $  1.6909110e+00
>   1.4550000e+03 $  1.7775459e+00
>   1.1800000e+03 $  1.8771469e+00
>   1.0000000e+03 $  1.9992190e+00
>   8.7500000e+02 $  2.1938025e+00
>   7.8300000e+02 $  2.5585915e+00

Note that the dollar sign separating the two column may be any character (ranging from a certain number of spaces, the \t (tab) char, a comma or just about any character that is uniquely used for the purpose of separating column. Also note that the data may have more than two columns.

Now I'd like to reformat the block of data such that all items from a certain column are listed in a single row (separated by the char that I marked as $ in the above example): The items from column 0 fill row 0, the items from column 1 fill row 1 and so on.

Is there a predefined emacs function to do that? Or if not, is there some "self-rolled" function to achieve that?

Also I'm very interested in a function that does the reverse thing, i.e. take some lines and put them in the column structure.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

You can use `csv-mode` (available from `package.el`). This is a simple transpose operation. To do so customize the value of `csv-separators` to `'("$")` and then use <kbd>C-c C-t</kbd>.

Comment: This works partially, after transposing I'm missing the separator char between the different items in the row.

Comment: It works here. Did you use customize to set the variable and restart emacs? I had problems when I set the variable directly in the session.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of practice:

```
(defun transpose-table (begin end &optional numcols)
  (interactive "r\nP")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char begin)
    (move-beginning-of-line 1)
    (let ((separators
           (if numcols
               (loop for i from 0 upto
                     (if (numberp numcols) numcols (car numcols))
                     for sep =
                     (read-string
                      (format "%d'th column separator (RET to terminate): " i))
                     until (string= sep "")
                     collect sep)
             (let ((x (list " "))) (nconc x x))))
          (end (save-excursion
                 (goto-char end)
                 (move-end-of-line 1)
                 (point))) lines)
      (loop while (< (point) end)
            for start = (point)
            for line = (buffer-substring 
                        start 
                        (progn (move-end-of-line 1) (point)))
            for numlines from 0
            with numrows = 0
            with longest-word = 0
            collect (loop for i from 0 below (length line)
                          with last-pos = 0
                          with rows = 0
                          with sep = separators
                          for sep-length = (length (car sep))
                          if (and (< (+ sep-length i) (length line))
                                  (string= (car sep)
                                           (substring line i (+ i sep-length))))
                          collect (substring line last-pos i) into words
                          and do (setf longest-word (max longest-word (- i last-pos))
                                       last-pos (+ i sep-length)
                                       sep (cdr sep) rows (1+ rows))
                          end
                          finally (return
                                   (progn
                                     (setf numrows (max rows numrows))
                                     (if (< last-pos (length line))
                                         (append words (list (substring line last-pos)))
                                       words))))
            into lines
            collect longest-word into word-lengths
            do (unless (eobp) (forward-char))
            finally 
            (loop initially (delete-region begin end)
                  for i from 0 to numrows do
                  (loop for line on lines 
                        for cell-length in word-lengths do
                        (if (caar line)
                            (let ((insertion (caar line)))
                              (insert insertion
                                      (make-string
                                       (- cell-length (length insertion) -1) ?\ ))
                              (rplaca line (cdar line)))
                          (insert (make-string (1+ cell-length) ?\ ))))
                  (insert "\n"))))))
```

Maybe using the one from `csv-mode` would be actually better, but you can try this one regardless :)

How it works: if you call it as <kbd>M-x</kbd>`transpose-table`, then it will assume that table columns are separated by single white space, however, if you invoke it with numeric argument (for example, <kbd>M-3</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd>`transpose-table`, then it will prompt you to collect 3 column separators. You could also call it like <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd>`transpose-table`, and opt out of providing all 16 separators by pressing <kbd>RET</kbd> when asked for extra separator.

I couldn't find proper ordinal printing of numbers function... so, sorry for "1'th" and "2'th" English :)

Comment: This is what I was looking for (something independent from the mode I'm currently using) but it has some bugs. For starters, it seems to lose the last column. Running on two columns I get one row (containing the items from the first column), working on three I get two rows, and so on. Furthermore, it appears that the prefix argument is not working, executing `M-3 M-x transpose-table` gives the error `let*: Wrong type argument: listp, 3` Also the reverse (row to columns) is loses the last entry (8 rows per col -> 1 row per "col" -> 7 rows per col).